# Formal character of local cohomology groups with support in Schubert cells

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, $G$ a connected semi-simple algebraic group over $k$ and $B$ a fixed Borel subgroup of $G$ with maximal torus $T$. Also denote by $W$ the Weyl-group of $G$.

Let $X$ be the (complete) flag variety of $G$ dimension $n$, hence we can assume that $X=G/B$. Furthermore let $x \in X$ be the unique fixed point of $B$ under the natural left action of $G$ on $X$. Then denote for $w \in W$ by $X_w=Bwx$ the corresponding schubert cell in $X$ with dimension $l(w)$.

According to p. 51 in Brylinskis paper "Differential operators on the flag varieties" we have that the formal character of $H^{n-l(w)}_{X_w}(X, \mathscr{O})$ is given by $\frac{e^{-w(\rho)-\rho}}{\prod_{\alpha \in R(B)}(1-e^{-\alpha})}$. Here $R(B)$ is the set the roots of $B$, hence the positive roots of $G$ with respect to $B$ and $\rho$ is the half sum of all positive roots of $G$ with respect to $B$. Finally he concludes that $H^{n-l(w)}_{X_w}(X, \mathscr{O})$ has highest weight $-w(\rho)-\rho$.

He refers to Kempfs "The Grothendieck-Cousin Complex of an Induced Representation" for a proof of this result. But when I look it up there, concretely Lemma 12.8, I would rather say that the formal character of $H^{n-l(w)}_{X_w}(X, \mathscr{O})$ is given by $\frac{e^{w(\rho)+\rho}}{\prod_{\alpha \in R(B)}(1-e^{\alpha})}$. So the sign changed everywhere. Hence it would have lowest weight $w(\rho)+\rho$.

Can anyone solve my confusion?

Comment: I am not familiar with Kempf's paper but the sign change suggest that there should be some kind of "reversion" -- switching positive roots with negative, one Borel with the opposite etc. In fact, Brylinski's filtration is ascending but Kempf's is descending (see Lemma 12.1).

Comment: That being said, as far as I can see, the results are really at odds.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but as far as I see they both started with some arbitrary Borel. That one chain is ascending and the other one descending follows just by considering in one case the dimension and in the other one the codimension.

Comment: You are correct. I spend few hours with the Kempf's paper and as far as I can understand it is self-consistent. But I don't understand corollary 11.10 and how he uses it to get 12.8.

Comment: How I understand to get lemma 12.8: Let $C$ be a schubert cell with respect to a Borel $B$ containing a $T$-fixed point $g$. By proposition 6.4 we have for the open nbh $N(C)$ of $C$ a T-equivariant isomorphism $N(C) \cong Z \oplus U$, with $Z=\bigoplus_{\chi \in J(C)}V(\chi)$ and $U=\bigoplus_{\chi \in -K(C)}V(\chi)$. Also $C=Z \oplus 0$. Hence with $A$ and $B$ from corollary 11.10 (and the discussion before the corollary) being $-K(C)$ resp. $J(C)$, we have that $Z_n=C$. The rest is plugging in corollary 11.10. What is your problem with 11.10?

Comment: As "geometric" and "algebraic" representations in the sense of Kempf seems to have the same characters.

Comment: I think I see it now. On page 380 Kempf introduces bold V and normal V which is space of linear forms of bold V (i.e. the dual of bold V).  In 11.10 he says that $[\chi]$ is the iso-class of a weight space (?) of normal V, i.e. of the dual space. The notation is not very clear to me, but it seems that curly Macaulay is Indeed built from the dual. Since the dualization introduces minus sign on the weights, so we should get what Brylinski claims and it's just hidden in the notation introduced in the claim of 11.10.

Comment: First of all he introduces them on page 312 ff. I thought also in this direction but then I got stuck/confused with the following. Let $\mathbf{V}(\chi)$ be the one-dimensional vector space, where $T$ acts with a character $\chi$. Then he denotes by $V(\chi)$ the space of linear forms of $\mathbf{V}(\chi)$. On page 313/314 he defines for $K[T]$-modules $M$ and the associated $T$-representation $\mathbf{M}$ the characteristic $(M)$ resp. $(\mathbf{M})$ in terms of the $\chi$-eigenspaces. Furthermore he says that $(M)=(\mathbf{M})$. But if its like you say wouldn't we have $(M)=-(\mathbf{M})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula 12.8 in Kempf follows by plugging in 6.5 into 11.10 (see comment by CJS under the question). In the statement of 11.10 Kempf defines $[\chi]$ to denote the isomorphism class of $V(\chi).$ Now $V(\chi)$ is the dual of $\textbf{V}(\chi)$ (see page 313 or 380) and the torus $T$ acts on $\textbf{V}(\chi)$ by $(g,v) \mapsto \chi(g) v$ (see p. 313) which makes the weight/character of $V(\chi)$ to be equal to $-\chi.$  This reconciles Kempf's result/notation with Brylinski's statement.

Comment: But then my question is still, why the characteristics in Kempf‘s work p.313/314 are the same and have not opposite sign?

Comment: My understanding is that he just defines the characteristics of algebraic representations  in a way which is incompatible with how $T$ acts. I have no idea why.